# How to ask for a password to mount crypted swap at boot time on Linux Mint 16 with initramfs-tools?

Tags: linux-mint, boot, password, swap, cryptsetup

I use encrypted home folders on my notebook, which prevents use of hibernation on standard setup, because - and for a good reason - besides encrypting the home folder with `ecryptfs`, it reformats the swap partition with one-time passwords each boot. Thats why it is impossible to share hibernation data (which is stored in swap) between reboots.

One way of enabling the hibernation without sacrificing the security is to use persistent password for the swap an ask user to enter it at system boot.

AFAIK the standard way to achieve it is by adding or modifying scripts in `/usr/share/initramfs-tools/scripts/local-top`, and there was a [solution to achieve it on Linux Mint 15](http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=42&t=18743&p=190446#p190446).

On Linux Mint 16, although the patch doesn't work anymore, although the file `/usr/share/initramfs-tools/scripts/local-top/cryptroot` didn't change between the ditributions. I guess there was introduced a difference on how the kernel handles those scripts. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Then why don't you rephrase the original? Please don't create duplicates on purpose.

Comment: @AdamRyczkowski Put a bounty on it for creating attention. (Or at least delete the old one before...)

Comment: @Alois Well, it is not an exact duplicate. Here I ask only why a hook on the `/usr/share/initramfs-tools/scripts/local-top/cryptroot` ceased to work on newer kernel, which might be answered by a broader spectrum of people.

Comment: @HaukeLaging I forgot about that option. I put a bounty on a original question. Let's see, if that helps.